# Через что заполняется тег : innerHTML или value?

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго вам времени суток! Вопрос конечно глупый, но к моему сожалению, не могу чётко сформулировать свой вопрос и обратиться за помощью к поисковым системам.

Допустим, на странице n-ое количество всяких разных тегов, которые будем заполнять текстом через атрибуты **value** и **innerHTML**.

Вопрос :

**Как узнать программно**, через какой атрибут заполняется тег, через **value** или **innerHTML**?

И сразу вопрос №2 :
В PHP есть такая интересная вещь, как переменная переменная, пример :

```
<?php
$var1 = 'variable!111';
$vb = 'var1';
echo $$vb;//выведет variable!111
?>
```

Можно ли в JS сделать нечто подобное, например вот так :

```
$prpt_of_el = 'innerHTML';
$var eec = document.getElementById('someEI');
alert(eec.$$prpt_of_el);//хотелось бы динамически обратиться к свойству элемента, 
тоесть $$prpt_of_el может принимать значение либо innerHTML либо value, в зависимости от значения $prpt_of_el
```

Очень надеюсь, что выразился достаточно понятно чтобы вы могли мне дать полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу

```
// допустим есть элемент
var el = document.getElementById("someId");
// допустим переменная whatToChange строка
// которая может быть строкой 'value' или 'innerHTML'
// достаточно просто обратится так:
var whatToChange = 'innerHTML';
el[whatTochange] = 'Some new innerHTML';

whatToChange = 'value';
el[whatToChange] = 'Some new value';
```

А програмно узнать довольно просто - нужно проверять элемент регулярным выражением заполняется ли он через value. Откровенно говоря не понял какая во всем этом необходимость, возможно вы что-то не так поняли и хотите что-то не то делать, опишите задачу которую вы пытаетесь решить таким способом

```
// тогда примерно так
function fillById(id, data) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if(el !== null) {
         var t = el.tagName.toLowerCase();
         if( t == "textarea" || t == "input" || t == "select") {
             el.value = data;
         }
         else {
             el.innerHTML = data;
         }
    }
    else throw new Error("Element with id " + id + " not found in the DOM");
}
```

Comment: Задача такая : в функцию передаётся несколько аргументов, один из которых содержит id элемента, куда будет записан результат запроса, а второй - куда будет записываться состояние запроса. Элемент может заполняться через innerHTML или value, условию просто нужно знать, использовать innerHTMl или value, чтобы заполнить эти элементы текстом.

Answer (score 1):

Ну как вариант создать массив тегов с заполнением по value (коих немного), и проверять, если текущий тег есть в массиве, то делаем по value, иначе по innerHTML.